# JavaFX. stop everything, except one process

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

```
public void close(){

    KeyValue opacity = new KeyValue(canvas
            .opacityProperty(), 0);
    KeyFrame end = new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(500),
            opacity);
    Timeline t = new Timeline(end);
    t.play();
    t.setOnFinished(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            stage.close();
        }
    });
}
```

I have such a method, that changes opacity before quitting from app. It works fine, but during these 0.5 seconds Im still able to interact with UI. The question is how to stop everything except this Timeline execution before quitting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depends on how you set up your project. You could add a pane over the entire scene. Well, that doesn't prevent anyone from using the keyboard. So an alternative would be to consume all events like this:

```
root.addEventFilter(Event.ANY, e -> {
  e.consume();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. it worked, though EventHandler was set on Scene scene, so in my case it is `scene.addEventFilter(Event.ANY, e -> { e.consume(); });`

Answer (score 0):

Call

```
stage.getScene().getRoot().setDisable(true);
```

before you start the timeline

Comment: Is doesn't work in my case, seems because that EventHandler is set on scene, not on root, but seems like setting EventHandler to root is common practice, is it true and if yes-why?